# PIL to Django ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I try to create an image from an url and save it in my django model. If the first part works fine, I do not know how to associate the generated file to my object.

This is my function to generate the image file:

```
def get_remote_image(image_url, merchant_product_path):
    im = None
    name = ''
    r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        name = urlparse(image_url).path.split('/')[-1]

        full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, merchant_product_path)
        if not os.path.exists(full_path):
            os.makedirs(full_path)

        im = Image.open(r.raw)
        if im.mode != "RGB":
            im = im.convert("RGB")
        im.thumbnail((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im.save(full_path + name, 'JPEG')

    return {'im': im, 'name': name}
```

And now, the part to associate this file to my object:

```
    i = get_remote_image(row['pict'], m.get_products_media_path())

    obj, created = ProductLine.objects.update_or_create(
    ...
    ...
    ...
    )

if i['im'] is not None:
    try:
        obj.main_picture.save(
            i['name'],
            ContentFile(i['im']),
            save=True)
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

This code works but unfortunately, mu pictures are created in the correct folder, objects are created/update but each one has no picture file :(
Can someone tell me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally found a solution:

```
def get_remote_image(image_url):
    im = None
    name = ''
    r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        name = urlparse(image_url).path.split('/')[-1]
        i = Image.open(r.raw)
        buffer = BytesIO()
        if i.mode != "RGB":
            i = i.convert("RGB")
        i.thumbnail((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        i.save(buffer, format='JPEG')
        im = InMemoryUploadedFile(
            buffer,
            None,
            name,
            'image/jpeg',
            buffer.tell(),
            None)

    return {'im': im, 'name': name}
```

and then:

```
obj, created = ProductLine.objects.update_or_create(
...
...
...
)
i = get_remote_image(row['pict'])
obj.main_picture.save(
    os.path.join(m.get_products_image_path(), i['name']),
    i['im'],
    save=True)
```

Hope this will help some other users in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

With a model like :

```
class ProductLine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

You can directly link the picture on your computer using is path instead of his binary content.

```
obj, created = ProductLine.objects.update_or_create(...)
obj.image.name = "/path/to/the/file"
obj.save()
```